# Magento Uncaught ReferenceError: productAddToCartForm

Tags: javascript, magento

I have an issue with my Magento website:

https://makedaadolls.com/store/eu/reemah-afia-brown-hair-9.html

When i try to add a product to my cart i have this message error on click:

`" Uncaught ReferenceError: productAddToCartForm "`

It was perfectly working, and without any modifications on files or sql (even restoring files and sql of 2 days ago) it just doesn't work anymore, i've the function in a script as u can see in source but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i have been 5 hours on this problem and i just found 10mn after posting, my bad thanks anyway guys !

Comment: i have check upon  your given url its working perfect